# windows: ping url fails but ping -4 url works in local network

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ipv6, ipv4

I have been learning some network and system administration and encountered a puzzling problem.

**SETUP:**

I setup a small local offline network with a Windows Server 2019 and a Ubuntu server hosting gitea. In the Windows Server I have assigned a static IP of `169.254.0.2` and installed DNS and DHCP roles. In the Ubuntu server I have assigned a static IP of `169.254.0.3`.

DNS has been configured with a primary zone `funlab.abc`. I created a single A record for `gitea.funlab.abc.` to point to `169.254.0.3`. DHCP has been configured to lease addresses from `169.254.0.100` to `169.254.255.254`. Subnet mask is 255.255.0.0.

**PROBLEM:**

With this setup, I successfully got client machines to connect to the local LAN network, transparently get a dynamic IP address, and access `gitea.funlab.abc` through the browser.
But in windows 10 client machines, I am unable to run `ping gitea.funlab.abc` in command prompt. I get an error message :

```
Ping request could not find host gitea.funlab.abc. Please check the name and try again
```

Git clone/push operations involving the  URL `gitea.funlab.abc` also does not work.

However I can run `ping -4 gitea.funlab.abc` successfully. Git clone/push operations can also work if I replace the URL with the static IP. `nslookup gitea.funlab.abc` works correctly as well.

**QUESTION:**

Why is this happening? What did I misconfigure such that ping and git commands do not work?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out ping and git commands works just fine when I change the IP address to 192.168.X.X. I guess windows treat the 169.254.X.X addresses differently.